# Find the first character from the word and replace it

Tags: php

I want to find the first character of the word from the sentence and I want to replace it with some other character.

**eg    '9322731525 , 9820231525, 23856141 , 9321154466'**

find character 2 at 1st position and replace it so the output would look like

**eg    '9322731525 , 9820231525, *93856141* , 9321154466'**.

I tried using `substr` but it didn't work.

Comment: for example, please add expected result also.

Comment: please elaborate it more..

Comment: And what have you tried with `substr`? Normally it should work

Comment: Also post what you tried.

Comment: Try this - `preg_replace("/^2 /", $replace_number, $word);`

Comment: please get clearer on that you are trying to achieve

Comment: The function is `substr_replace`  and not `substr` .

Comment: I have a sentence eg '9322731525 , 9820231525, 23856141 , 9321154466' and I have to find which word has starting letter 2 in the sentence. If any word has starting letter 2 then I want to either replace the whole word or the 1st character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best regex in the world but I think it does what you need

```
$s='9322731525, 9820231525, 23856141, 9321154466';
$pttn='@\s2.@';
echo preg_replace( $pttn, ' 9', $s );

outputs
-------
9322731525, 9820231525, 9856141, 9321154466
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to do so: `'/ 2/'` with a space and a ,

to replace the first letter:

```
$string = '9322731525 , 9820231525, 23856141 , 9321154466';
$string = str_replace(',', ', ',$string);
$string = preg_replace('/ 2/', ' 9', $string);
output : 9322731525 , 9820231525, 93856141 , 9321154466
```

to replace the whole word:

```
$string = '9322731525 , 9820231525, 23856141 , 9321154466';
$string = str_replace(',', ', ',$string);
$string = preg_replace('/ (2[0-9]* )/', ' yourNewWord ', $string);
output : 9322731525 , 9820231525, yourNewWord , 9321154466
```

Comment: I tried it but it is replacing all the other word which has number 2. I wanted to replace only the 1st character of the word with starting letter 2 .

Comment: @nikalldway see here it is working: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ddR
only the starting 2 are replaced

Comment: You should see the 1st line @nikalldway

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
 substr_replace("2","9",0,1);
```

Have a look on [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr-replace.php) to see, how this function works.

Comment: It did not worked. I have a sentence eg '9322731525 , 9820231525, 23856141 , 9321154466' and I have to find which word has starting letter 2. If it has starting letter 2 then I want to either replace the whole word or the 1st character

Comment: Okay, I got it, than you can just split your text at a comma (using `split`-function), and then check every element of the array with the `substr_replace` function and after you did that building your sentence together again

Comment: I have lot of data and there r some words which does not have comma at the starting or ending or there are space between the comma. There by I have to search by word.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
echo preg_replace('/2/', '9', $yourstring);
```

Comment: He doesn't want to remove every 2 in the string, just the first.

Comment: Yes this will replace all the word consisting 2 . I wanted to replace only the 1st character of the word with starting letter 2